# Can you solve a linearly independent ODE's homogeneous part without the particular solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example $y''-6y'+9y=xe^{3x},\hspace{5mm} y(0)=0,y'(0)=0 $

I was wondering if it is possible to compute the homogenous solution even before working out the particular solution to this equation.

As an aside, I was wondering if the initial conditions are (0,0) for y' and y then is it not the case that I don't need the particular solution. As, in effect I am only lookin at the homogenous side of the equation.

I think my misunderstanding comes form the fact that in $y_{c}=y_{p}+y_{h}$ i see $y_{p}$ as a translation or rotation of the solution space away from the origin, and therefore if the inital condition are centered at (0,0) then I know the solution must exist in $y_{h}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the problem $$y''-6y'+9y=xe^{3x},\hspace{5mm} y(0)=0,y'(0)=0$$

as if it was a homogenous problem and plugging in indeed results in the actual (IVP-solved) general solution to the inhomogenous problem.

General solution:

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{6}e^{3x}x^3+e^{3x}c_1+e^{3x}c_2$$
IVP-General solution:
$$y(x)_{IVP}=\frac{1}{6}e^{3x}x^3$$

**A counter-example would be:**

$$y''-6y'+9y=e^{3x}+cos(x),\hspace{5mm} y(0)=0,y'(0)=0$$

Where the general solution is:

$$y(x)=\frac{2}{25}\cos(x)-\frac{3}{50}\sin(x)+e^{3x}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}c_1x+\frac{1}{2}c_2\right)$$

The IVP-general solution on the other hand is:

$$y(x)_{IVP}=\frac{2}{25}\cos(x)-\frac{3}{50}\sin(x)+e^{3x}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{15}{50}x-\frac{4}{50}\right)$$

In which the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ are clearly not zero.

Comment: Yes I do mean, can we solve y′′−6y′+9y=0, without solving the general equation

Comment: Do you mean solve y′′−6y′+9y=0 without the inhomogenous part or solve y′′−6y′+9y=xe^3x without the inhomogenous solution or solve y′′−6y′+9y=0 without the initial conditions (y(0), y'(0))

Comment: I meant: could I solve  y′′−6y′+9y=0 without the inhomogeneous part, as in could I find the constants to the solutions of  y′′−6y′+9y=0(which is part of the larger equation ), by using initial conditions without every finding the inhomogeneous part down to the fact of the initial condition being  y(0)=0 and y'(0)=0

Comment: Actually this is a really interesting idea. I never thought of this. This way of thinking works for this specific problem, but i cannot give you a formal proof for this.

Comment: It is just interesting to think of, but I somehow think there is a flaw in the way I am thinking of all this

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: If you are interested in this kind of visual understanding of differential equations i can recommend you to look up 'phase spaces' or maybe 'Symplectic Geometry'

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, and for pointing to the idea " 'phase spaces' or maybe 'Symplectic Geometry' "